# Keep alive request for _change continuous feed

Tags: http, go, couchdb, keep-alive

I am trying to convert below nodejs code to Go. I have to establish keep alive http request to PouchDB server's _changes?feed=continuous. However, I'm not able to achieve it in Go.

```
var http = require('http')

var agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

var options = {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: '3030',
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/downloads/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true',
   agent 
};

var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        let val = data.toString()
        if(val == '\n')
            console.log('newline')
        else {
            console.log(JSON.parse(val))
            //to close the connection
            //agent.destroy()
        }
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        // Data received completely.
        console.log('end');
    });

    response.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
});
req.end();
```

Below is the Go code

```
client := &http.Client{}
data := url.Values{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:3030/downloads/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true", strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))

req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
fmt.Println(resp.Status)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

I am getting status 200 Ok, but no data gets printed, its stuck. On the other hand if I use longpoll option ie. http://localhost:3030/downloads/_changes?feed=longpoll then I am receiving data.

Comment: You should consider using a library to do this work for you. There [are several](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Go).

Comment: @Flimzy I had used Kivik, but I faced similar issue. Hence decided to communicate directly to couchdb. https://github.com/go-kivik/kivik/issues/467

Comment: Thanks for the link. That issue looks completely different than what you've described here. In any case, I answered your Kivik issue with some suggestions.

Comment: I am extremely sorry but I am using pouchDB, I thought apis are similar. Hence mentioned couchDb.

Comment: The APIs are similar, but their underlying functionality is completely different. PouchDB runs entirely in the browser, CouchDB runs on a server.

Comment: The code you've included in your question is obviously _not_ using PouchDB.  You cannot talk to PouchDB with an HTTP `GET` request.

Comment: @FlimzyI am using pouchdb server. pouchdb-server --port 3030 --in-memory

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue. The issue was related to `DisableCompression` flag. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16488 this issue gave me some hint.

By setting `DisableCompression: true` fixed the issue.
`client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{
    DisableCompression: true,
}}`

I am assuming `client := &http.Client{}` sends `DisableCompression : false` by default and pouchdb server is sending compressed json, Hence received data was compressed and resp.Body.Read was not able to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working "as expected" and what you wrote in Go is not equivalent to code shown in Node.js. Go code blocks on `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` because connection is kept open by CouchDB server. Once server closes the connection your client code will print out `result` as `ioutil.ReadAll()` will be able to read all data down to EOF.

From [CouchDB documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/changes.html#continuous) about continuous feed:

> A continuous feed stays open and connected to the database until explicitly closed and changes are sent to the client as they happen, i.e. in near real-time. As with the longpoll feed type you can set both the timeout and heartbeat intervals to ensure that the connection is kept open for new changes and updates.

You can try experiment and add `&timeout=1` to URL which will force CouchDB to close connection after 1s. Your Go code then should print the whole response.

Node.js code works differently, event `data` handler is called every time server sends some data. If you want to achieve same and process partial updates as they come (before connection is closed) you cannot use [ioutil.ReadAll()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) as that waits for EOF (and thus blocks in your case) but something like `resp.Body.Read()` to process partial buffers. Here is very simplified snippet of code that demonstrates that and should give you basic idea:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    data := url.Values{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:3030/downloads/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true", strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        l, err := resp.Body.Read(buf)
        if l == 0 && err != nil {
            break // this is super simplified
        }
        // here you can send off data to e.g. channel or start
        // handler goroutine...
        fmt.Printf("%s", buf[:l])
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

In real world application you probably want to make sure your `buf` holds something that looks like a valid message and then pass it to channel or handler goroutine for further processing.

Comment: Hi blami, I had tried resp.Body.Read before with no success. However I tried it once again as you suggested, but not working. On the other hand, nodejs code works perfectly fine

Comment: @Pram by "not working" you mean it still blocks indefinitely?

Comment: @Pram just to clarify, using my snippet it doesn't print any data and block or do you see data coming through and then it blocks?

Comment: I don't see any data printed by fmt.Printf("%s", buf[:l]) at all

Comment: I edited my answer and posted minimal full file executable example for triage. I just tested it against locally running CouchDB in Docker and it behaves same as your Node.js code (should print out some data and then block). If this one works fine in your env then there's other issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212541/discussion-between-blami-and-pram).